# Nested for loops to create pyramid

Tags: java, swing, loops, nested

I was wondering if someone could help figure this out. I've been trying to display a pyramid using nested for loops and I've only been able to get the first row (base row) working. The pyramid is suppose to have 10 rectangles at the bottom and as it increments up, the rectangle count decreases to 9, 8, 7, 6, etc. I've been looking at this for days and have had no luck.

Thank you!

```
public class Legos2 extends JFrame {
private int startX;
private int startY;
private int legoWidth;
private int legoHeight;
private int baseLength;
private int arcWidth;
private int arcHeight;

// Constructor
public Legos2() {
    super("Jimmy's LEGOs");
    startX = 20;
    startY = 300;
    legoWidth = 50;
    legoHeight = 20;
    baseLength = 10;
    arcWidth = 2;
    arcHeight = 2;
}

// The drawings in the graphics context
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{

    // Call the paint method of the JFrame
    super.paint(g);


    int currentX = startX;
    int currentY = startY;

    //row = 0 is the bottom row
    for (int row = 1; row <= baseLength; row++)
    {   
        currentX = currentX + legoWidth;
        if (row % 2 == 0)
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
        else
            g.setColor(Color.red);
        System.out.println(row);


        for (int col = 0; col <= baseLength; col++)
        {
            System.out.println(col);
            g.fillRoundRect(currentX, currentY, legoWidth, legoHeight, arcWidth, arcHeight);

        }
        //currentY = currentY - legoHeight;
    }
}

// The main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Legos2 app = new Legos2();
    // Set the size and the visibility
    app.setSize(700, 500);
    app.setVisible(true);
    // Exit on close is clicked
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currentY value should be decremented at each iteration of the outer loop: for each row, you want to restart from a lower Y. So you should uncomment the line

```
//currentY = currentY - legoHeight;
```

The currentX must be incremented after each column, so at the end of the inner loop, and not at the beginning of the outer loop. And it must be reset to the start X position of the current row before you enter the inner loop.

If you just reset currentX to startX, you'll get a wall of bricks. But you need a pyramid. So there should be one less iteration of the inner loop at each iteration of the outer loop, and the startX should also be incremented after each iteration of the outer loop:

```
    for (int row = 1; row <= baseLength; row++) {
        currentX = startX;
        if (row % 2 == 0) {
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
        }
        else {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
        }
        System.out.println("row = " + row);


        for (int col = 0; col <= baseLength - row; col++) {
            System.out.println("col = " + col);
            g.fillRoundRect(currentX, currentY, legoWidth, legoHeight, arcWidth, arcHeight);
            currentX = currentX + legoWidth;
        }
        currentY -= legoHeight;
        startX += legoWidth / 2;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!! Do you have any recommendations on java resources that I should check out. my professor teaching style is to just read slides and I have been struggling this whole semester learning on my own.

Comment: "Effective Java" by Josh Bloch is a great book, but probably a bit too advanced if you're still struggling with logic, algorithmic and syntax. The best way to learn is to practice. Sometimes, leaving the screen and using a pen and a paper saves a lot of time.